# Android Converting Object to String Array

Tags: android, eclipse

To set the scene: I have a Fragment that executes an AsyncTask. Here is the fragment.

```
package com.IB.ecko;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

public Object objarr[] = new Object[3];
Bitmap ProfileImages[];
String UserInfo[] = new String[6];
String UserInfo2[];
String Summary;
private ImageButton ProfileImageButton;
private TextView UsernameTextView;
private TextView AgeTextView;
private TextView PersonalityTextView;
private TextView SummaryTextView;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_profile_fragment, container, false);

    ProfileImageButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.ProfileImageButton);
    UsernameTextView = (TextView)  v.findViewById(R.id.ProfileViewUserNameTextView);
    AgeTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ProfileViewAgeTextView);
    PersonalityTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ProfileViewPersonalityTextView);
    SummaryTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ProfileViewSummaryTextView);

    //Download Profile
    NetworkAsyncDownload task = new NetworkAsyncDownload(objarr);
    task.execute();
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return v;
}
public void SetViews(){
    UserInfo = (String[]) objarr[0];
    ProfileImages = (Bitmap[]) objarr[1];
    Summary = (String) objarr[2];
    UserInfo2 = (String[]) objarr[3];
    ProfileImageButton.setImageBitmap(ProfileImages[0]);
    UsernameTextView.setText(UserInfo[0]);
    PersonalityTextView.setText(UserInfo2[4]);
    AgeTextView.setText(UserInfo[3]);
    SummaryTextView.setText(Summary);
}

}
```

Here is the AsyncTask.

```
package com.IB.ecko;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.net.SocketException;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;

import android.content.Context; 
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NetworkAsyncDownload extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Object[]> { 


FileOutputStream desFileStream;
FileInputStream fileinputstream;
ObjectInputStream objectinputstream;
Object input1;
Object input2;
Object input3;
Object input4;
Object objarr[];
Bitmap ProfileImages[];
String UserInfo[];
String UserInfo2[];
String Summary;

private final WeakReference<Object[]> ObjArrRef;

public NetworkAsyncDownload(Object obj[]){

    ObjArrRef = new WeakReference<Object[]>(obj);

}

@Override
protected Object[] doInBackground(Void... params) {

        desFileStream = new FileOutputStream(path + "JUIFromServer");
        mFTPClient.retrieveFile("JUI", desFileStream);
        fileinputstream = new FileInputStream(path + "JUIFromServer");
        objectinputstream = new ObjectInputStream(fileinputstream);
        input1 = objectinputstream.readObject();
        mFTPClient.retrieveFile("ProfilePictures", desFileStream);
        input2 = objectinputstream.readObject();
        mFTPClient.retrieveFile("Summary", desFileStream);
        input3 = objectinputstream.readObject();
        mFTPClient.retrieveFile("JUI2", desFileStream);
        input4 = objectinputstream.readObject();
        objarr = new Object[] {input1, input2, input3, input4};

    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return objarr;
}
 protected void onPostExecute(Object object[]) {
     objarr = ObjArrRef.get();
     objarr = object;
     ProfileFragment SetViews = new ProfileFragment();
     SetViews.objarr = object;
     SetViews.SetViews();
 }

}
```

When I load the fragment, here is the error log it gives me.

```
10-07 03:28:21.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7759): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-07 03:28:21.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7759): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-07 03:28:21.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7759):     at com.IB.ecko.ProfileFragment.SetViews(ProfileFragment.java:44)
10-07 03:28:21.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7759):     at com.IB.ecko.NetworkAsyncDownload.onPostExecute(NetworkAsyncDownload.java:85)
10-07 03:28:21.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7759):     at com.IB.ecko.NetworkAsyncDownload.onPostExecute(NetworkAsyncDownload.java:1)
10-07 03:28:21.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7759):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
10-07 03:28:21.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7759):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
10-07 03:28:21.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7759):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
10-07 03:28:21.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7759):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-07 03:28:21.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7759):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-07 03:28:21.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7759):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
10-07 03:28:21.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7759):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-07 03:28:21.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7759):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-07 03:28:21.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7759):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
10-07 03:28:21.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7759):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
10-07 03:28:21.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7759):     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:110)
10-07 03:28:21.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7759):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The error seems to be caused by :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 10-07 03:28:21.358:E/AndroidRuntime(7759): at com.IB.ecko.ProfileFragment.SetViews(ProfileFragment.java:44)
```

Which is this line right here: `UserInfo = (String[]) objarr[0];`

Sorry for the naming, it wasn't my intention for the code to be reader friendly. 
objarr is an array of objects that I had saved. objarr[0] is a String array. I have done this before in a different activity but not quite as complicated with the whole fragment and AsyncTask stuff going on, just within the activity. I'm not sure what's causing the error. You'll probably see some redundant code that was a result of me trying random things to make it work and then see what caused it. Also, I deleted all the network code stuff. Let me know if I should tidy up this post so it's easier to read.

Comment: I would recommend to just output your objarr and see if it is null. And if not, output your objarr[0] and see what is in it. The exceptions says, that there is a nullpointer. So somehow objarr[0] == null, or objarr == null. So somehow objarr = ObjArrRef.get(); does not return, what you expect.. check this.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you have `ProfileFragment.objarr = new Object[3]`, but each of that objects is null.

When you initialices an array (new Object[]) you reserve space for contains objects, but each object is null until you instance its. For example, like this:

```
ProfileFragment.objarr[0] = new String[6];
```

Then, you can do:

```
UserInfo = (String[]) objarr[0];
UserInfo[0] = "name";
UserInfo[1] = "surname";
....
```